# Problems with algebraically finding the range of a square root of a quadratic function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have written down my reasoning and my working out in the attached pictures. To summarise, I have successfully found the domain of the function: 
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{2-x^2} 
$$
I know how to graphically find the range of the function but what I am stumped at is how to algebraically find the range. I am using the fact that the domain of the inverse of the original function $f(x)$ is the range of the original function. Can you please read the pictures attached and help me out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're not allowed to simply _recognize_ that the given function takes the curve of a semicircle and therefore its maximum value is the length of the radius above the origin?

Comment: @AndrewChin Correct. It has to be evaluated algebraically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the sheer length of your argument, I think you're overcomplicating matters. Consider:

- $\sqrt x \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0$ and is continuous
- $x^2 \ge 0$ for all real $x$ and is continuous
- Therefore, $-x^2 \le 0$, then $2 - x^2 \le 2$, and therefore $\sqrt{2-x^2} \le \sqrt 2$

What this argument shows is that all values in the interval $[0,\sqrt 2]$ must be achieved, because of continuity and the function involved. We show that $f(x)$ is bounded above by $\sqrt 2$ and below by $0$. You can verify these values are achieved for $x = 0$ and $x=\sqrt 2$ respectively. Continuity gives us that every value in-between is also achieved.